# Blender rigid body Bullet implementation unstable? Compared to Lightwave 3D Bullet implementation for sanity check

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Long term Lightwave3D user switching to Blender. I like a lot about it, however this has me baffled:

I have been trying to get Blender's rigid body dynamics working for some hours now and I just can't seem to get this stable. Now, I did browse the web and any earlier questions/answers I could find here and tried any suggestion provided. But most just seem to say that unstable/exploding rigid body dynamics is due to overlapping polygons.

However, I have no issues doing this in Lightwave3D which is seemingly using the same physics engine Bullet. See a simple import from Mecabricks with relatively standard rigid body parameters in LW3D. It is stable at first, then I fire a cannon ball through it. Result is as intended and most of the model remains cohesive:

[image: Lightwave Bullet rigid body dynamics]

Mecabricks actually has a great Blender importer add-on, but for the sake of comparison I imported the same Collada file as in Lightwave and get the following result, typically from the first frame of simulation it starts breaking up fast:
[image]

4 frames in there is 0 cohesion left:
[image]

See for example a reduced Blend file here: [image]

Both programs seem to use Bullet, why does Blender appear to have more issues with it?

Suggestions tried:

- Made scale appropriately large for Bullet (same for both programs)
- Applied transformations, made sure all objects are single user
- Reduced collision margins
- Increased world rigid body settings
- Tried about any parameter for the rigid bodies
- Triangulated the poly's

Should I file it as a bug?

Comment: I suspect the parenting of the imported  objects might be the cause. Try clearing those first.

Comment: What parenting are you referring to? There is none of significance that I am aware of..

Comment: What are all of those lines that fan from the center?

Comment: @susu objects appear to be parented to an empty if you look closely

Comment: @Timaroberts that is exactly what I wonder about. Some imported objects have the placement of different parts depend on some other object (or empty), so I wonder if the bullet engine is being affected by that.

Comment: All lego bricks are parented to a null at 0,0,0 which is the lines you see. I am used to parenting to a Null in order to keep scene outlines tidy.. Clearing the parent does not change anything to the simulation however.